# Nginx+Tomcat+Geoserver+Ubuntu setup block

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, tomcat, geoserver

I have an issue with my nginx setup regarding Geoserver (working on Tomcat)  which runs in Ubuntu 18.04. My block is:

```
server {
  server_name domain_name;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/tomcat-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/tomcat-error.log;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
  location /geoserver {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
  listen [::]:443 ssl; 
  listen 443 ssl; 
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain_name/fullchain.pem; 
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain_name/privkey.pem; 
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;


}
server {
    if ($host = domain_name) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain_name;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

At first, it worked perfectly but, after I rebooted my server, it returns 502 Bad Gateway. Checking the tomcat error log it says

```
*52 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: **.***.***.**, server: domain_name, request: "GET /geoserver/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/", host: "domain_name"
```

What is wrong with this setup? Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: is your tomcat Appserver up and running. Check `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep "LISTEN"` and check if there is port `8080` with the Tomcats PID.

Comment: It seems that you got something there. There is no port 8080 for tomcat. Now what?

Comment: Start your Tomcat Appserver to listen on Port `8080`.  How to start depends on how you have installed it ...